# Unable to connect Core Service with SOAP UI

Tags: core-service, web8.5, sdl-tridion

I am trying to connect SDL WEB 8.5 Core Service using SOAP UI to get the XML format of the request.

However While Trying to Connect I am facing issues, I'll be using `WshttpBinding` to connect also using `Stream Upload` client.
I've used `NTLM` type Authentication for connection.

[image: Settings while trying to connect]

[image]
I am able to connect to web service using .NET code snippet with below settings.

**Binding Details :**

```
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttp" transactionFlow="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
        <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="10485760" maxArrayLength="10485760"/>
        <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
        </security>
    </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

**Code Snippet**

```
_client = new SessionAwareCoreServiceClient("");
if (_client.ChannelFactory.Credentials != null)
{
    _client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential(domain\username, password);
}
```

Regards, Tarun

Comment: I've been able to connect to SDL web service using Soap UI, however it is done using a proxy tool Burp as mentioned in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914899/testing-web-service-with-soapui-and-windows-authentication